# Case statement two buttons under selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to put to buttons under the same case such as:

```
    when "invited"
         button_to "Confirm", .... 
         button_to "Refuse", ....
```

At the minute only one of the buttons is shown at the time, how can I do to show both simultaneously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typically the case that only the last result is returned, so if you want to return multiple things:

```
when 'x'
  [
    button_to ...,
    button_to
  ]
...
```

That will return an array with all of the various buttons present.